# Title bar changer for windows

Tags: windows, title-bar

I would like to get a Title changer software for windows. I googled and tried the following

1. Window Title changer by MurGee.com
2. EPC Title Bar Changer.

But nothing worked in a good manner !!! Could you please suggest some other ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish that these softwares don't provide?

Comment: @techie007-For eg, EPC Title Bar Changer is intended to change the title bar and title icon of any windows,which can change text and icon of any window's title bar,add antiboss key(hot key) to minimize or close all windows or hide all tray icons,automatic change window's title bar according to historic changes

Comment: Ok, sounds good.  So what's the problem? :)

Comment: @techie007 : The window retain its original name after some minutes, I felt it in Visual Studio 2008

Comment: You should edit your question to clearly include what it is you are trying to accomplish, and a brief explanation as to why these softwares didn't fulfill those requirements. It will help get better answers.

Comment: @techie007 Could you please suggest some other ?